# Group Json data with two keys and get the total count

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, group-by, grouping

Is there a way to group the JSON Array with 2 keys and get the counts of grouped object key in Javascript.

Need solution in Javascript.

https://pastebin.com/raw/FLB7vFhC

Expected Result:
the length of the counts object should be 5 only, with the sum of all the keys grouped together.

```
[
  {
    "totalCount": 3,
    "counts": [0,0,3,0,0],
    "productID": "tea1",
    "keyVal": "key5",
    "trend": "0"
  },
    {
    "totalCount": 4,
    "counts": [2,2,0,0,0],
    "productID": "tea1",
    "keyVal": "key1",
    "trend": "0"
  },
  {
    "totalCount": 11,
    "counts": [0,5,6,0,0],
    "productID": "group1",
    "keyVal": "key2",
    "trend": "0"
  },
  {
    "totalCount": 616,
    "counts": [101,507,8,0,0],
    "productID": "group1",
    "keyVal": "key1",
    "trend": "0"
 },
]
```

Comment: What is the input? We need more details to help you

Comment: Added the link from pastebin

Comment: So fast to add a negative point..

Comment: @PankajKumar well, if you would've provided a better explanation and what you've already tried, that would not have happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I've missed the second key

There you go:

temp1 = the json input in the pasteBin

You should adjust the trend variable, since it was not specified how to calculate it.

```js
function groupBy(array, f) {
    var groups = {};
    array.forEach(function(o) {
        var group = JSON.stringify(f(o));
        groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
        groups[group].push(o);
    });
    return Object.keys(groups).map(function(group) {
        return groups[group];
    })
}

var result = groupBy(temp1, function(item) {
    return [item.keyVal, item.productID];
});

var output = [];
result.forEach(grouped => {
    var count = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0];
    var totalCount = 0;
    var trend = 0;
    var productID = grouped[0].productID;
    var keyVal = grouped[0].keyVal;
    grouped.forEach(value => {
        totalCount += value.totalCount;
        value.counts.forEach((x, i) => count[i] += x)
    })
    console.log(count);
    output.push({
        counts: count,
        keyVal: keyVal,
        totalCount: totalCount,
        productID: productID,
        trend: trend
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort , but the result is not same as the expected one.. you have grouped it by keyVal..It should be grouped with keyVal and productID